# Python How To Assign 2 Variables in One Part(?)

Tags: python, list, variables, tuples

Im sorry ı couldn't write decent title. But let me explain.

a list that holds ten variable 
`list[0] = tshirt` 
but if user search t-shirt in that list, program should accept it as tshirt. 
What Im asking is, can I say

```
list[0] = "tshirt" or "t-shirt"
```

if not, must I do that manually or is there any way to do this?

thanks.

Edit: Can any mod fix my title so people can understand the problem and find answer below

Comment: `list[0] in ("tshirt", "t-shirt")` or `list[0].replace('-', '') = "tshirt"`

Comment: You could make use of a tuple, `("tshirt", "t-shirt")`, which you can access the same way as you would an array (e.g. `list[0][0]` or `list[0][1]`). `or` is a boolean operator, so it cannot be used in the way that you tried.

Comment: What if the user enters `tee-shirt`? It can be tedious listing all the possible variations. If your example was exploring an issue with wider application then you might want to look as the **fuzzywuzzy** module which scores strings on how close they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember , I faced this issue too in one of my projects.There is a python library called fuzzywuzzy which tells if two words are similar or not based on the similarity score.Here's an example stuff.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
temp = "t-shirt"
if fuzz.token_sort_ratio("tshirt", temp) > 70:
    print("Found")
if fuzz.token_sort_ratio("TSHIRT", temp) > 70:
    print("Found")
if fuzz.token_sort_ratio("T--SHIRT", temp) > 70:
    print("Found")
```

> It Outputs FOUND for all three statements.

This library provides us a solution to a problem which most of us might have faced.

Answer (score 0):

You can either check for two values using the `in` operator:

```
list[0] in ("tshirt", "t-shirt")
```

or check for "tshirt" only but replace all occurrences of `-` with empty spaces, so that both "tshirt" and "t-shirt" (changed to "tshirt") actually match.

```
list[0].replace('-', '') = "tshirt"
```

Check the Python [demo](https://www.online-python.com/kj7Bs8zUO5).

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand but, you want to ignore the "-" character?

```
if list[0].replace('-','')=="tshirt":
    True
```

That would be very bad use. You should better explain what you need.

Comment: Im sorry if I couldn't explain myself. English is not my main language. I have a list and lets say my list have a "tshirt" in itself. Then I will put a input and if user write
t-shirt as tshirt I want output to be true. Should I write every misspelled word in that list or can I use something for it. Like if tshirt in that list is first item:
list[0] = tshirt, t-shirt, tshrt
I hope I explained myself better.
Thanks.

Comment: and one note: I did tried your code but got an error says " type object 'list' has no attribute 'replace' "
Python version on my mac is Python 3.10.9.
What can be wrong?
thanks.

Comment: and If anyone can explain. What is "-" character means?